# how to convert file from .rtf to .pdf with LibreOffice programmatically in PHP language

Tags: php, pdf

My situation is this: I have a portal with CMS drupal and it runs on virtual machine with Windows server 2008 RC. Now the portal create a file from .rtf to .PDF and into the file there are some tags that they are changed with fileds's content of the data base. All the process make of use PDFCreator installed into virtual machine and in language php

$command_shell ='c:\programmi\PDFCreator.exe /IF" '.$base ....ecc; 
exec($command_shell);

I must do this process described above with LIBREOFFICE..How can I do?

Error from command line

[image]

Comment: Might be of help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140537/run-terminal-commands-from-within-libreoffices-basic-programming

Comment: Are there api of LIBREOFFICE to convert programmatically from file rtf to pdf?

Comment: I would like to know the syntax command to execute in PHP

Comment: I have tried on cmd in windows to execute the command: soffice.exe --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf:C:\Programmi\Apache Software Fondation\Apache2.2\htdocs\..\..\*.rtf --outdir C:\Programmi         ....but it doesn't convert anything

Comment: And what is the output message in cmd?

Comment: Also, close LibrOffice when you execute the command, and put the paths between double quotes.

Comment: Message is: "Libreoffice has stopped working" Problem Event Name: APPCRASH. I post the screenshot

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling libreoffice?

Comment: yes, I have reinstalled, but always the app crash

Comment: It worked with OpenOffice + JODConverter. THANKS